# Grails can't connect to a datasource, but psql can?

Tags: grails, jdbc, postgresql

**Grails definition:**

```
development {
   dataSource {
     driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
     dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
     pooled = false
     jndiName = null
     url = "jdbc:postgresql://10.197.6.214:5432/mydatabase"
     dbCreate = "create-drop"
     username = "myusername"
     password = "password"
   }
}
```

**psql statement which can connect:**
`psql -h 10.197.6.214 -d mydatabase -U myusername`

**pg_hba.conf:**

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0          trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
```

**postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port=5432
```

How could this possibly be happening?

More info:
It looks like if I start grails from the machine running the database, startup works, but if I try from another machine, startup fails, despite psql connecting without issue.

Comment: can you connect on the app server machine from the CLI?

Comment: Yes. psql from the app-server connects.

Comment: and no info is sent back about the failure?

Comment: Just a generic "Connection refused."

Comment: weird, something basic must be off.  is there any info in the db machine's logs about why the connection was refused, both the db and the server logs?

Comment: `Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is acceptaing TCP/IP connections.`

Comment: It looks like postgres logs all the attempts to drop the appropriate tables, but no creates are ever issues, and there is nothing indicating why the creates fail.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `DataSources.groovy` definition had a bad entry, which caused the main connection bomb at the bottom of the stacktrace. Tracing all the way back up, I had a bad secondary datasource definition.